# jQuery .load() not working with PhoneGap Build and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am working on a jQuery Mobile web application. It is a single index.html file with multiple pages within using `data-role="page"`. Each page uses the same headers and footer, so I am using `.load()` to load separate html files within my project.

This works as expected in Chrome, but not when I install the application to my iPhone running iOS 8.3. The headers and footer simply do not load.

```
/*** load headers and footer ***/
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
    /* header */
    $('.customHeader').load('../templates/header.html');
    /* footer */
    $('.customFooter').load('../templates/footer.html');
    /* dining */
    $('.banner.dining').load('../templates/dining.html');   
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this other than white-listing the domains?

Answer (score 0):

I have had jQuery not working for me too on phonegap. A couple things, I changed. Hopefully this helps.

Did you wrap the code on the document onready()?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

)}:
```

For some reason, when I put the document ready, it works. The web works differently.

Also, make sure you jquery includes are before your script. My jQuery wouldn't work unless these were before my code:

```
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My code is wrapped in `$(document).on('pageinit', function() {});`, but didn't work when I tried `$(document).ready(function() {)}:` My source order is also correct. I load my custom scripts last.